# pip freeze doesn't show global packages - Windows

Tags: python, django, pip

I ran "pip freeze" in my command prompt and it only listed local packages that i installed into my venv(virtual environment)

While smy script used some packages like datetime where installed globally

Here is what i did -

1.Ran pip freeze inside my venv(after activating my venv)
OUTPUT -

```
Django==1.9.2
requests==2.9.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
```

Note - I installed these three packages locally inside my venv.

2.Ran "pip freeze" outside(after deactivating my venv / new command prompt window) still same output

```
Django==1.9.2
requests==2.9.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
```

I have many packages installed globally, here are few

```
1.datetime
2.urllib.parse
3.selenium
4.lxml
5.bs4
6.openpyxl
and more.
```

Through IDLE i can still import these packages, they are working fine.

Why does pip freeze list only local packages?
And how to get the list of all installed packages(global) so that i can create a requirements.txt

Additional details - I have two versions of python installed (py3.5 , py2.7)

Comment: What do you mean outside your virtualenv? Did you deactivate it? Or choose a different terminal?

Comment: After deactivating my venv, yes.

Comment: Depending on your system, you may have either `pip2` or `pip3` and a default `pip`, try ony of these maybe? Like `pip2 freeze`

Comment: pip2 freeze still outputs the same result, while pip3 throws an error - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Comment: I can be very wrong, but maybe pip isn't able to access the directory for read access, try `sudo pip freeze` .

Comment: Forgot to mention i'm working on windows.

Comment: Ohh well, good luck then. I don't have much experience with windows, but you can always try to manually run pip from `C:\PythonPath\scripts`, just run `python pip.py freeze`, see if that works. It maybe that your paths are configured wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because i had both python3.5 and python2.7 installed.
And because of this the pip was called from python2.7(which has lesser packages).

How i solved this issue -

1.Uninstalled python2.7, deleted the python2.7 folder.
2.Ran the python3.5 setup and selected "Repair" option and it worked like a charm.

Now "pip freeze" returned all the installed modules from python3.5.